# React-Navigation Parameters not ever passing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Ok, I have managed to pass parameters so far, but on this specific situation, I wasn't able to identify why this functionality is not working.

Basically these are my navigators that are set:

login-nav.js:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; 
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import { LoginScreen } from '../screens/login-scr';
import { SignupScreen } from '../screens/signup-scr';
import { NewPassScreen } from '../screens/new-pass-scr';

import { MainStack } from './main-nav';

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator (  
  { 
      Login: {   
                screen: LoginScreen, 
                navigationOptions: { 
                 header: null, 
                }, 
      },

      NewPass: { 
                screen: NewPassScreen,

      },

      SignUp: {
                screen: SignupScreen,
      },

      MainStack: {
        screen: MainStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },
  },   
); 

const AppContainer =  createAppContainer(LoginStack); 

export {AppContainer};
```

main-nav.js:

```
import React from 'react'; 

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';

import { MainScreen } from '../screens/main-scr';
import { TasksScreen } from '../screens/tasks-scr';
import { AgendaScreen } from '../screens/agenda-scr';

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';



const BottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:     {
              screen: MainScreen,
              navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel:"Home",
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                  <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={20} color={tintColor} />
                )
              }

            },
  Tasks:    {
              screen: TasksScreen,
              navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel:"Tarefas",
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                  <Ionicons name="ios-checkbox-outline" size={20} color={tintColor} />
                ),  
              },
            },

 // Agenda:   {screen: AgendaScreen},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});



const MainStack = createStackNavigator (  
  { 
      Main: {
        screen: BottomTabNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },

  },   
); 


export  { MainStack };
```

Now this is how I pass the parameter from the Login screen (Actually how I am doing now, I've tried several different ways):

login-scr.js:

```
... 

handleSubmit = ()=>{

...
                  console.log("Login passed from login-scr ===> " + this.state.login);
                  const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
                    params: { Login: this.state.login },
                    key: 'Home',
                  });

                  this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);

                  this.props.navigation.navigate("MainStack");

...

}
```

And this is how I'm receiving:

main-scr.js:

```
async componentDidMount() {

...
        let llogin = this.props.navigation.getParam('Login', 'notFound');
        console.log("Login on Main Screen ====>  " + llogin  );
...

}
```

I wanted to save the llogin variable to my states, but it is always comming as 'notFound'.

Is there anything peculiar in this route that I didn't find out, that I should treat differently+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of upgrades on React-Native to use stateless functions, React-Navigation changed a lot the way it works on version five. That also changed a bit the way the routes are passed. Best solution was to migrate to version ^5 and rewrite the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass your params inside `this.props.navigation.navigate`

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("MainStack", {
    Login: this.state.login
  });
};
```

For more information check [passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Comment: Actually this is how I tried it first... it wasn`t working so I changed to the other way. In  both ways I receive undefined from the getParam... I don't understand why...

Comment: what is the output value of ```console.log(this.state.login)```

Comment: the output is an e-mail address, 'email@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

I still wasn't able to find out why this particular case is not passing the parameters. I suspect it could be due to the fact of using the structure Stack Navigator --> Bottom Navigator --> Stack Navigator --- > Screen.

The best way to work around this that I found was creating a class in a separated javascript file, instantiate an object in it and import/export from the places I want to use the values, updating it accordingly...